# How to fetch data from mysql according to the UserID and match it with the users info in php back to Xcode display

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode

I got a registration form in my application in Xcode and I use PHP code to upload users data to mysql database. Now any ideas how can I retrieve users data from mysql with php by each user? In other words how can I put this users information into a profile ViewController according to the current UserId?.
What strategy should I use to achieve my goal,
Is this approach is even possible?
Should I use core data for saving Users Information?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the `iOS` part, but it is possible to grab users from a `MySQL` table.

Before you start, it is important that your userID column is set to contain unique values.  An easy way to accomplish this is to set userID as a primary key.  If this is not possible due to your table setup, check the link below:

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/1828

On the php end, it would be as simple as creating a query based on your userID:

```
SELECT * FROM (table) WHERE userID = $variable
```

Where $variable is the userid in your php code and (table) is the table without the ().  See the link below for info on connecting to a database in PHP:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

**UPDATE**

From your screenshot, it appears that you are using phpmyadmin.  If you click the "structure" tab you may add userID as a primary key by clicking on the key icon next the userID column, and clicking "Next."
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is how my UserID structure in mysql look like take look: http://postimg.org/image/llpybp5c7/

Comment: I have addressed your screenshot with an edit to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You could start using [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) in your `application`, have it post the user supplied information to your server and then if the response is valid (not a duplicate account, all fields completed etc) you could pass it to whatever `ViewController` using the `prepareForSegue` method.

If you wanted to implement CoreData, RestKit provides this functionality out of the box (needs some configuration).

Using the Master Detail Template in xCode you could configure your server to respond with a list of users (MasterTBVC) and when one is selected show the detail (DetailVC).

There are some [tutorials](http://restkit-tutorials.com/) out there to help get started with RestKit.

Comment: Hey thank you for you're answer mate, what if I don't want to use CoreData and want to stay with php mysql..?

Comment: That is no worries, RestKit provides classes for both. It is usually a little easier to implement, in my experience, without CoreData. Basically CoreData would really only give you some local persistence of some data, RestKit won't mind if you don't want to go down that road and happily make requests to the php/mysql server for all its information.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right...

On `PHP` side use a normal `$_POST['userid']` to get the user id requested from your App... Then use MySQL to get the Data where id = $_POST['userid'] and put it into an array, (fetch_assoc) which should be echoed like json_encode(array)

You can trigger it with a NSUrlConnection on your script, and serealize the response to a NSDictionary...

It will be a matter how big your User Data will be... If it is just the Name and an ID, write it to `NSUserdefaults`... From there you can easily access it all over your whole App...

If you need to save more, or bigger data, just put the JSON you get from your PHP to an NSDictionary and use its writeToFile method to write it into a .plist file in your Documents Directory

Comment: Hey thank's for you're answer dude, I got a lot of information so can you maybe show my this on a query of getting it back with this array you said? does this array is necessary for this? (look down my comment to Larry Borasto Please).

Comment: Well sorry I dont get what you want, do you want a SQL Query from me? Or obj. C / Swift Code? Or PHP Code?

Comment: everything will be great together in one example

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps by adding some `PHP` code to query the `database` that you just updated?

Comment: What? I don't want an update query this will be my next step for saving user profile changes like "edit profile" button for instance and then "save" button

Comment: Ok, my answer was a bit flip but implied the same result as @Anthony above. You said you had PHP code to add user info to a MySQL db, which I assumed that you call via HTTP. You would simply add another method, as Anthony suggests, to retrieve the information for the desired user, and send it to the iOS app, probably in JSON form.

And NSURLRequest in the iOS app will retrieve the info, which you can parse into an NSDictionary and then display in your view controller.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, how does the xCode.. know which UserID Is been getting if I use Select query do you know my friend? this is my main issue here... Let's say I used select from my table userId where user Id = $userid (just basic example) when I use SELECT query on php how does the php know which userid row to take from the mysql database..?

Comment: It would use the value that you pass in your HTTP GET (or POST) request: '$userIdToFind = $GET['id']`.

Unless you are asking how your app would know the user ids. If that is the case then you should probably have the PHP code that updates the database return the user id of the new record for you to save. Down voting my answer because I didn't just write the code for you is a bit harsh though.

Comment: So lets see if I got it right.If I use $POST UserID it is basically an array by it self and I don't need to crate an array or a $SESSION right ? and then when I call this: SELECT FROM.. and use select the: UserID it got coocikes alerady or somthing like array that knows which userID to take from the database hhh did I got it right?

Comment: Yes. If you call a url like `http://myserver.com/getuser.php?id=1` then your getuser.php script will have a value of 1 for $_GET['id'].

Comment: But do you know if this array/value whatever.. also work/been saved on an Appplication in xcode?

Comment: The same array will not have been saved in the iOS application. The PHP code that adds the entry to the db should return it to you for you to save.